# How to get user_likes from Facebook SDK

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

Im trying to get the user's likes from Facebook, I've been looking for a while for an example and I didn't find it. 
With the code I have I get the user's profile information, but no likes. I was wondering if I was doing something wrong and then I looked at Facebook Developers and I found this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/user-data-ios-sdk/

If you take a look at the JSON that is returned you won't see any likes, so what does that mean? There's no way to fech the likes of a user? Why even bother calling the permission "user_likes"?

Any direction will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can someone give a hint? Is this disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's put it this way. Facebook documentation is confusing. 
To get he user likes you have to use FQL, the snippet, would be something like this.

```
// Query to fetch the active user's friends, limit to 25.
NSString *query =
@"SELECT page_id, type FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me()";
// Set up the query parameter
NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
// Make the API request that uses FQL
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                             parameters:queryParam
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                          }
                      }];
```

This way you are getting the users Pages id. If you need something else, take a look at the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan